# Почему поток STA становится MTA?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Я запускаю `BackgroundWorker` в `STA` потоке после завершения работы в событии `RunWorkerCompleted` текущий поток становится `MTA`... 
почему? 
Ведь `ProgressChanged` и `RunWorkerCompleted` должны быть в `STA` или нет?

```
Worker = new BackgroundWorker
{
    WorkerReportsProgress = true,
    WorkerSupportsCancellation = true
};
Worker.ProgressChanged += (sender, args) => ProgressChanged(args); //MTA
Worker.DoWork += WorkerOnDoWork;
Worker.RunWorkerCompleted += WorkerOnRunWorkerCompleted;
Worker.RunWorkerAsync();

private void WorkerOnRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
{
   //Тут уже MTA 
}
private void WorkerOnDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs args)
{
   //Тут перенаправляется в другой domain
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Прежде всего, STA и MTA — не «названия» потоков, и лишь их свойство.

Поведение `BackgroundWorker`'а таково. Пусть вы запускаете `RunWorkerAsync` в потоке `A`. `BackgroundWorker` использует в процессе работы другой поток из пула, назовём его поток `B`.

Тогда

- `DoWork` выполняется в потоке `B`,
- `RunWorkerCompleted` и `ReportProgress` доставляются в поток `A`.

Передачи в другой `AppDomain` не происходит.

Эта схема работает, если поток `A` обладает *контекстом синхронизации*, то есть, если в него *можно* передать управление. Это условие выполняется для UI-потоков в WinWorms и WPF, но не для потоков, созданных вручную, или потоков приложения командной строки.

Для случая отсутствия контекста синхронизации всё происходит в потоке `B`.

Теперь, поток `B` берётся из пула, и, следовательно, является MTA-потоком. Поток `A` может быть, а может и не быть STA-потоком. Однако, для случая UI-потока WinForms или WPF (то есть, того случая, когда контекст синхронизации для вас создан фреймфорком) этот поток будет STA-потоком.

Думаю, что вы запускаете `BackgroundWorker` из потока, не имеющего контекста синхронизации.